# different partition size in parted and in df

Tags: partitioning, df, parted

Can anyone explain the difference between partition size in parted and in df?

```
root@HOME:~# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) u s                                                              
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 488397168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start       End         Size        File system  Name                  Flags
 1      2048s       206847s     204800s     fat32        EFI                   boot
 2      206848s     468991s     262144s                                        msftres
 3      468992s     134686719s  134217728s  ntfs         Win10                 msftdata
 4      134686720s  268904447s  134217728s  ext4         ubuntu
 5      268904448s  436676942s  167772495s  ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata

(parted) q                                                                
root@HOME:~# df -BG
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4            63G    7G       53G  12% /
none                  1G    0G        1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                  4G    1G        4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1G    1G        1G   1% /run
none                  1G    0G        1G   0% /run/lock
none                  4G    1G        4G   1% /run/shm
none                  1G    1G        1G   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1             1G    1G        1G  30% /boot/efi
root@HOME:~#
```

Size of /dev/sda4 is 134.217.728 sectors, which is 134.217.728*512 = 68.719.476.736 bytes.

It is **EXACTLY** 64GiB, as 64*1024*1024*1024 = 68.719.476.736

Why df shows "63G" ?

Comment: could be related to this http://superuser.com/questions/289678/du-vs-df-output

Comment: My question is not about the free size inside a partition, but about the overall partition size. I don't see any relation to that thread.

Comment: Have you tried `df -H`?  Tells it to use the powers of 1000 and not 1024.

Comment: `parted` with `u kib` shows 67108864kiB
It is correct: 67.108.864 / 1024 / 1024 = 64

`df -BK` shows 65922812K
It is wrong: 65922812 / 1024 / 1024 = 62.86889267

Comment: `df -H` shows 68G - totally wrong
`df -h` shows 63G - it is also wrong...

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10778/111521  Looks like a pretty good explanation of where the size goes.

Comment: Thank you, Terrance. That's really should be the answer...

Comment: You're very welcome!  =)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `df` shows the space available in the **file system** (without structures needed for the file system itself maybe?), whereas `parted` probably reports the outer size of the **partition**.

Other than that, the output of `df -BG` seems to be rounded down to full GigaBytes. I think that the sizes would differ less if you let `df` output smaller (optimally the same as `parted` i.e. 512 bytes) units.

Comment: df -BK (the smallest unit for df, I assume) shows
`root@HOME:~# df -BK
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      65922812K 7033496K 55517440K  12% /`
Which is also wrong:
65.922.812 / 1024 / 1024 = 62.86889267

Comment: `df -B512` shows 131.845.624

It is also wrong, according to `parted` is should be 134.217.728

Comment: @Tice As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**